# Multiplying matrices to get a specific result

Tags: matrices

Are there matrices $A,B$ (of dimension $n$), that give
\begin{equation}
AB-BA=I
\end{equation}

I have tried getting a result in small scale by using $2\times 2$ matrices and got a false equation $(0=1)$.
But I cannot find a way to show that it is true for all $n$.
I tried showing it by definition but that didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the trace on both sides.

Comment: I figured out the the trace of AB is the same as BA, but that doesnt mean that each part of A is equal to the same part in B. Am I missing something?

Comment: @yinoneliraz If $AB-BA=I$ had a solution, $0=\frac{\text{trace of the LHS}}{n}=\frac{\text{trace of the RHS}}{n}=1$, which would give your "false equation".